# FIND_IN_SET Query fails

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble with a `FIND_IN_SET` query. I can get the basic query to work but when I replace the search terms with PHP variables it fails.

```
if ($_GET['picId']) {
    $query_class    = $_GET['query_class'];
    $query_subclass = "picSearch";
    $criteria       = "&#40;FIND_IN_SET &#40;".$_GET['picId'].",pic_IDs&#41;&#41;" ;
    $criteria_value = "&gt;0";
} 
$tbl_name = "expo_data";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE $criteria $criteria_value");
```

If I use a hard coded query it works fine.
say "look for all occurrences of a picture with id=3 in column pic_IDS"

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE (FIND_IN_SET(3,pic_IDs))>0");
```

If I `echo $criteria` and `$criteria_value` the results "Look" OK.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Before you run the query echo it out and see if it looks right. I'm assuming the issue is with the html entities that should be parenthesis. Also, SQL Injection warning.

Comment: **$criteria = 'FIND_IN_SET ('.$_GET['picId'].',pic_IDs)';**

Comment: MySQL does not expect HTML entity-encoded characters `()<>`. Those need to be literals defined in your criteria strings - the string variable contents should be exactly as you hard-coded them.

Comment: The previous two comments allude to SQL injection vulnerabilities: see [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for an explanation of how you must handle `$_GET['picId']` in this query.  At a minimum, you should call `intval($_GET['picId'])` to cast it as an integer.

Comment: Thanks Alex, that fixed it. OK, Jonathan & Michael, I get the message! I'll look into the SQL injection. I have had a quick look at your link and my brain is still hurting! Is there an idiots guide for people like me?